# How do you kill Dr. Lugae?

Tags: final-fantasy-4

I'm getting sick of these stupid boss battles.

This guy casts "Reversal" so that damage becomes healing and healing becomes damage. This means I can't heal my party with "cure". Then he proceeds to cast some spell I don't remember the name of that deals 1000+ damage to each party member over and over.

How on earth do you kill this guy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're lucky, you'll have found an **Elixir** along the way and not used it.

Use it on him after he uses Reversal, and it's pretty much over.

Should you need to do a little more damage, you can use your healing spells and items *on him*. Throwing Potions, Cure spells and more at him should make quick work of an otherwise difficult boss. If you need to heal while under the effects of Reversal, Rydia can heal your party with *Black Magic*. It goes both ways after all. Remember to have Yang use Focus to charge up his attacks while Reversal is active, and everyone should be able to stay occupied.

**An alternate strategy** is to have Rydia summon Whyt at the start of the fight, *before* the first use of Reversal Gas. It'll throw Rydia's status out of sync with the rest of the party; this effectively renders her completely immune to Lugae's attacks, at which point, you can just take your time with it.

Comment: Do you know if there's any way to revive fallen party members while under the effects of reversal? Phoenix Downs don't work.

Comment: I don't believe there is one... You can wait it out, or better yet, use black magic to heal yourself and stay ahead of it. Once you understand the Reversal gimmick, it really is quite manageable.

Comment: Well, it worked, but Cecil died to his Frankenmonster's self destruct beforehand and missed out on experience.